# Bootstrap4 how to add iamge above navbar text?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4. I am trying to replicate navbar with icon above the text as follow.I tried creating my own class and using  but it breaks the format of nav

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

button{
  border:none;
  padding:0 20px;
}

img{
width:50px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='nav'>
  <button class="btn">
   <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg">
   <span>Support</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah something like this .. however i wish to use my own .png icon

Comment: Okay, now replace value of `src` in `img` tag.

Comment: it's breaking the format.. my current way of nav bar is 

               <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">

          About
        </a>
      </li>

Answer (score 0):

The styling have nothing to do with `nav`

HTML:

```
<a class="nav-with-icon">
  <img src="/image/path/photo.jpg />
  Support
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-with-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I didn't try but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want. However how can I replace the icon image to my own image instead of using the class? when i use image tag it breaks the entire nav bar

Comment: just replace the `span` to `img`. edited in my answer